# Can Rigidbody and Character Controller be used together?

Tags: unity-game-engine

First of all, please understand that I am using a translator.I was working with a character controller and needed detailed physics. For example, micro-floor crash test, the strength of applying force to an object, etc. I've already done a lot of work on the character controller. So I thought it was too late to fix the code from scratch with a rigidbody. In conclusion, can I use a character controller and a Rigidbody together?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not a good idea to use a **character controller** and a **Rigidbody** together in a game because they serve similar purposes and can conflict with each other (they 100% will). A character controller is a component that is intended to be used for **character movement** and provides collision detection and response for the game object it is attached to. A Rigidbody, on the other hand, is a component that is used to add **realistic physics** to an object in a game.

You could potentially disable the controller and enable the rigidbody when a specific event occurs and vice versa.